# Billing Variance Analysis With Many Scenarios - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was given tens of thousands of bills charged to customers. I am trying to determine if the bills are potentially accurate. The only data I have is the actual bill itself. Here's where things get complicated. There are four scenarios, each with their own nuances:

Scenario 1 Nuances:

1. Base Fee of $10 * the amount of items bought * the number of deliveries (maximum amount of items bought would be 10 and the maximum number of deliveries would be 7)
2. If the amount of items bought exceeds 1, the total bill is discounted by 20%
3. If the boxes are recycled, the total bill is further discounted by 15%
4. If the good is over 15 pounds, an additional charge of $10 will be assessed per each item over 15 pounds (maximum amount of items would be 10)
5. If there is no adequate port for delivery, an additional $50 per hour will be charged per delivery (maximum hours would be 3)

Scenario 2 Nuances:

1. Business that share a port of delivery for the second service will be charged $11 per item
2. If the business does not share a port of delivery, the fee is $13 per item. Each additionally delivery for a business that does not share a port is $15 per delivery, in addition to each item costing $13 (maximum deliveries would be 7 and maximum amount of items would be 8).

You see where I am going with all of this. The next two scenarios are just as lengthy. Sadly, no information besides the total bill is given. We don't know which scenario the bill belongs to, the number of items, etc., just a single column of the invoice. How would I go about determining all potential costs from each scenario to maybe index the invoice and see if there is a match? Any help on this would be amazing.

I tried creating an index where I wrote out multiple scenarios. For example, a column with the number of items, the number of deliveries, a discount for > 1 item bought, a recycling discount, etc... After attempting this for two hours, I realized this may not be the best method. My first row would be 1 item, 1 delivery, 0% discount for > 1 item bought, and 0% discount for recycling. Next would be 2 items bought, 1 delivery, 20% discount for > 1 item bought, 0% discount for recycling. This is seemingly impossible to do for everything.

My expected output is "Y" if the invoice total matches one of the potential costs from the index, "N" if not.

Comment: This is a wall of text with what looks like one question:  *How would I go about determining all potential costs from each scenario to maybe index the invoice and see if there is a match?*, which would be out of scope for StackOverflow.  Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58140266/edit) to provide a scope that is more objective towards answering a *specific* question.  We can try to help correct issues you're having with your specific formula/code, but this is neither a discussion nor code-for-you forum.

Comment: Where would I go to ask a question like this? I was advised to ask here so if you could direct me to the appropriate forum it would be highly appreciated :D

Comment: I doubt there's anywhere you can ask a question like this and reasonably expect an answer - there are so many unexplained items in there.  For example "tens of thousands of bills" is what *exactly*?  A big box full of paper?  A text file?  If a set of data or an Excel file, what information do you have in there and exactly how does it relate to your scenarios and all those rules ?  If you really need to evaluate all possible outcomes and just compare them to a list of charges that seems like you'd get a ton of false positives.

Comment: It's a single column with each cell containing the invoice total. It's in an Excel worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macro to calculate every possible scenario. Write a macro with [nested loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/control-flow/nested-control-structures).

- The outside loop is the quantity, such as `For ItemQty = 1 to 100` (or to some other likely maximum).
- The inside loops are the scenarios and nuances, such as `For BoxesRecycled = 0 to 1`. Each loop modifies the total, such as `Total = Total - (BoxesRecycled * 0.15 * Total)`.
- In the middle of all the loops is code that writes a line with the quantity, nuances, and total.

You will need to match the sequence in which charges and discounts were applied and the way the total was rounded. Probably the sequence was discounted 20%, then discounted 15%, then rounded. But maybe it was discounted 20%, then rounded, then discounted 15%, then rounded. If you don't match the sequence and rounding, then your total might be 1 cent different from an actual invoice.